# Why often Laravel 5 uses method_exists instead of abstract methods?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, abstract-class

FYI: I am using Laravel 5.5

One of the example:

when you do: `php artisan make:request TestRequest`
artisan generates `TestRequest` class which extends from `FormRequest` class and with generated 2 methods: `rules()` and `authorize()`

Let's have a look to `passesAuthorization()` method in `FormRequest` class:

```
protected function passesAuthorization()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'authorize')) {
            return $this->container->call([$this, 'authorize']);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

For me it's strange behavior:

I would make `FormRequest` as Abstract class and would add 2 abstract methods: `rules()` and `authorize()` and after in `TestRequest` I would implement them.

*Could someone please explain, why here is such behavior?*

Comment: the difference is that you build an app thats why you would go with an abstract class since you prolly know possibue use casses and method calls, while building a framework its whole another story! What if user tries to call a method that does not exist in your abstract class etc...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, but I could be wrong. In designing framework, your aim is to not overload your user with plethora settings and configurations. Most of these `method_exists` are actually ensuring the existence of an optional method before executing it. If you define it as abstract, you will trouble your user by ensuring them to implement an empty method when they don't really need it.

In this `FormRequest`, it uses trait `ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait`. This trait explicitly overwritten the `passesAuthorization` and returned true ([source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/862724bdfccf7233ccc154f11df0afff1213f7f8/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.php#L66-L73))...

```
protected function passesAuthorization()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'authorize')) {
        return $this->authorize();
    }

    return true;
}
```

... which also equal to not doing authorization check if the user do not implement method `authorize`, which make it optional! Of why this trait is used, I found [a blog post](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/laravel-5.0-validateswhenresolved/) about it that you could take a look at it (totally unrelated to this question).

Anyway, I guess the benefit of avoiding abstract methods could be:

- Less tightly coupled code between framework and user code
- Made them optional, so you don't need to just implement the method for doing nothing.
- More trait friendly and less conflicts?